# Using definition of Riemann Integral to evaluate indefinite integral

Tags: integration, analysis, definite-integrals

Let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by 
$ f(x)=\begin{cases}
1 & x\in[0,1]\backslash\left\{ \dfrac{1}{2}\right\} \\
-1 & x=\dfrac{1}{2}
\end{cases} $.

Based on inspection, it's pretty obvious that $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\mathrm{d}x=1 $. However, I don't know in particular how to go about partitioning [0,1] and using tagged partitions to find this seemingly simple sum. I know that if I let there be some $\xi_i\in[x_{i-1},x_i], \text{for some } i=1,2,...,n $, then since most of this function is 1, that $f(\xi_i)=1$ for all $x\not= \dfrac{1}{2}$. However, I don't know how to take care of the outlier, and am also wondering if there's anything I'm missing or over-thinking.

Comment: Show that the difference between this and the regular integral is less than $\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy to verify that $f$ is Riemann integrable: take the partition $\displaystyle P_n=\Big\{0<\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}<\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}<1\Big\}$ and note that $$\displaystyle L(f,P_n)=1\cdot\Big(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}\Big)+(-1)\cdot \frac{2}{n}+
1\cdot \Big(1-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}\Big),~U(f,P_n)=1,$$ so $U(f,P_n) -L(f,P_n)\rightarrow 0,~n\rightarrow +\infty$ (using Riemman's integrability lemma: a bounded function $f$ on $[a,b]$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ iff $U(f,P_n) -L(f,P_n)\rightarrow 0,~n\rightarrow +\infty$ for a sequence of partitions $(P_n)$ of $[a,b]$). Note that for all $n$:

$$L(f,P_n)\leq \sup_P L(f,P)=\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx\leq \inf_P U(f,P)\leq U(f,P_n)$$
where $P$ are partitions of $[0,1]$, so taking  the limits an $n \rightarrow +\infty$, you get  $\displaystyle 1\leq  \int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx\leq1$, as desired.

[image]